# Where can I create, update and store my iPhone backend

Tags: iphone

I have found a lot of sites that can store my data but I also would like a web service that can run my three php files regularly to update the data in my database. I have these files because I need to get data from another source and make it more suitable for my needs and then I save them into JSON files which I later want to access from my iPhone app. Is there any place that can do this (hopefully for free or cheap)?

Comment: are you talking about webservice invok in background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some sites for free, but you're better off paying for a service IMO. You're looking for something with "MySQL Databases" as a feature. iPage.com, WebHostingHub.com, BlueHost.com, etc. all offer this.

Comment: I agree with bdev. Here is one trick I use to get the first 2 years free - go through a rebate site, like cashbackhouse.com - many of these sites give you $50/100 for signup. Here is my bookmark - http://www.cashbackhouse.com/retailers.php?cat=45 I don't see ipage on this, but found it when I did a search.